# Why T is in the covariance position or contravariance position

Tags: scala

1. Given the following class definition

   class X[+T] {
     def get[U>:T]`(default:U)`:U
   }

why T in the method `def get[U>:T]`(default:U) is in the covariance position

2. Given the following class definition

   class X[-T] {
     def get[U<:T]`(default:U)`:U
   }

why T in the method `def get[U<:T]`(default:U) is in the cotravariance position

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is hard to answer "Why?" question without you providing more details but I'll try. I assume that your question is really "why type restriction on `U` are not inverted?". The short answer: because this is type-safe and covers some cases that are not covered otherwise.

Your first example is probably inspired by `Option[T]` and its `getOrElse` method. Although I'm not sure why anybody needs `getOrElse` with `U` different from `T`, logic why type restriction can be only `U>:T` seems obvious to me. Let's assume you have 3 classes: `C` which inherits `B` which inherits `A` and you have an `Option[B]`. If your `default` value is already `B` or `C` you don't need anything beyond `U` = `T` and thus simpler signature without additional generic `U` would suffice. The only case when you can't pass default value to the `getOrElse` method is if you have it of some type which is not a subtype of `B` (such as `A`). Let's extend this signature even more for a moment

```scala
def getOrElse[U, R](default:U): R
```

How types `U`, `T` and `R` should be related? Obviously `R` should be some common super-type of `U` and `T` because it should be able to contain both `T` and `U`. However such definition would be an overkill. First of all it is really weird to have default value of a type that is not related to the `T` at all. Secondly, even if it is such a strange case, you (and compiler) still can calculate a common super-type and assign it to some new `U'` = `R'`. Thus you don't need `R` but adding `U` adds some more flexibility (at least theoretically). But `U` still has to be some super-type of `T` because it is also the return type.

So to sum up: adding `U` with `U<:T` will

- either produce wrong code if you use `U` as the result type (`U` as a result type can't hold `T`)
- or if you use `T` as the result type would not extend applicability of this method i.e. would not allow any code that does not compile without `U` to compile with this additional `U`.

But adding `U` with `U>:T` will allow some more code which is actually type-safe to compile such as (yes, stupid example but as I said I don't know any real life examples):

```scala
val opt = Option[Int](1)
val orElse: Any = opt.getOrElse(List())
```